# Removing shading from a text field in Microsoft Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a Microsoft Word document that has a weird background in some of the text fields that I can't figure out how to remove. I tried setting Shading to `No Color` and style `Clear` but it doesn't seem to affect the text field in any way.

You can see the shading here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you need to go to **File** > **Options** > **Advanced**, scroll down to the **Show document content** section, and change the setting of the **Field shading** field. Chances are, it's currently set to **Always**. In this case, changing the shading setting and clearing the style doesn't have any effect, because the text isn't *really* shaded gray (that is, it wouldn't be shaded if you were to print the doc or generate a PDF of it); Word is merely alerting you to the presence of a field.

Comment: Field Shading is set to `Never`

Answer (score 0):

The shading shows *input fields*. You can define how input fields are shown in the view settings; but be aware that they are normally only shaded on the screen, not on a printout (actually, that is another option in newer versions, so you also *print* it shaded)

Comment: The printing part is actually why I'm asking this. It prints the shading for those fields. I check print settings and don't see how to disable that.